# Hot code replace no longer working in Eclipse for Groovy?

Tags: eclipse, debugging

Hot code replace is no longer working for me in Eclipse for Groovy.  I have a project with a mix of Groovy and Java files.  This morning hot code replace worked, but now it doesn't work for Groovy. It still works for Java files.  I'm not sure what the difference is that made it stop working.

Any suggestions?